# Determining T38 packet using either C or C++

Tags: c++, c, packet, analyzer, decoder

I am working on analyzing a packet using C/C++.
At present I am stuck at one place. I researched a lot but was not able to find an appropriate solution. I am still searching but thought if anyone could help me out over here. How can I uniquely determine a T38 packet?
Is there a specific protocol value or specific hex value that represents a T38 packet?

Awaiting a positive response.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Look the folowing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547201/looking-for-a-t-38-library

Comment: @VolAnd: Thanks for your reply. I referred to the post you provided, but I was unable to find out the way to determine T38 packet. I checked the code of HylaFAX+ and Asterisk, but I was not able to get my requirements, as there are many files in it, I checked many files but was not successful. I just need to determine T38 protocol in a packet. Could you please let me know, if you know the way to determine T38 protocol?

Comment: No, I do not. Sorry!

Comment: Ok. Thanks..Do let me know if you have any other inputs..it will be very helpful to me..:)

Comment: Have you read this document http://www.sipforum.org/component/option,com_docman/task,doc_view/gid,412/Itemid,261/  ?

Comment: Hi @VolAnd thanks a lot for your continuous help. I referred the document as pointed by you. Its very helpful, but still could not find the unique trick to identify a T.38 packet. Actually in current context of my work everything is working fine for T38 packets, but sometimes non T38 packets are also getting identified as T38 packets which we want to avoid. Actually we dont want to decode the T38 packets, we just want a unique way to identify only T38 packets.

Comment: I suppose, that detection you want can be impossible at all. And that fact will force you refer to the  artificial intelligence (some pattern recognition methods)